# Sylius v1.0.0 simple form extension

Tags: sylius

I have a problem to extend the form. I just want to change the birthday format in EU style (dd.MM.yyyy). So i create the src/AppBundle/Form/Extension/CustomerProfileTypeExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

final class CustomerProfileTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

// Change to EU Style dd.MM.yyyy
$builder->add('birthday', BirthdayType::class, [
'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
]);
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getExtendedType()
{
return CustomerProfileType::class;
}
}
```

and i changed the AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml to

```
services:
app.form.extension.type.customer_profile:
class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\CustomerProfileTypeExtension
tags:
- { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType }
```

BUT NO CHANGE. Cache clear not helping me!
I also just changed like in the sylius example to remove the gender field or changing the required to true - its not working.

Any idea / help ?

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I forgot to import the services.yml ´- { resource: "services.yml" }´ in my config.yml

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it threw an error as you are missing the following line

`use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;`

in fact, remove

`use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;`

as it's not being used, and replace it with the BirthdayType line

Once I added that, it worked fine.

John

Comment: Hi John, i don't know why... its not working for me. I try to do this also for the form to register. No success. To be sure... all i was writing is correct? I mean the path and there is nothing else? No change in the config? So fare this is also 1by1 in my services.yml. Or is there anything missing?  THX Mike

Comment: Ah, spotted a difference between what you've done and what I did last night. Put the services definition in app/config/services.yml and give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

O.K. - to make it correct:

acme/src/AppBundle/Form/Extension/CustomerProfileTypeExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

final class CustomerProfileTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

// Change to EU Style dd.MM.yyyy
$builder->add('birthday', BirthdayType::class, [
'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
'required' => true,
]);
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getExtendedType()
{
return CustomerProfileType::class;
}
}
```

acme/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
app.form.extension.type.customer_profile:
class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\CustomerProfileTypeExtension
tags:
- { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType }
```

Same -no change - if i change to here.
acme/app/config/services.yml

No change of the field. No error - also no when i clear the cache.

Comment: I'm having the same issue , Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to import the services.yml  `- { resource: "services.yml" }` in my config.yml